# Is it possible to skip setUp() for a specific test in python's unittest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, python-unittest

When I create a `unittest.TestCase`, I can define a `setUp()` function that will run before every test in that test case. Is it possible to skip the `setUp()` for a single specific test?

It's possible that wanting to skip `setUp()` for a given test is not a good practice. I'm fairly new to unit testing and any suggestion regarding the subject is welcome.

Comment: An example use-case: I am functional testing an application which uses an external API. Nearly every method requires `setUp()` to authenticate with the server, except if I were testing the `login()` function itself.

Comment: Related on [softwareengineering.se]: [*Is it possible to have setup and tear down methods run only for specific unittests?*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/232243/168744)

Comment: Related to: [Python unittest, do something only if test fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30647772/python-unittest-do-something-only-if-test-fails/)

Comment: A `@unittest.skip_setup` decorator would be nice to have, similar to [@unittest.skip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.skip). I guess [victortv's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56710965) is the closest thing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp) (italics mine):

> `unittest.TestCase.setUp()`
>
> Method called to prepare the test fixture. This is called immediately before calling the test method; any exception raised by
>   this method will be considered an error rather than a test failure.
>   *The default implementation does nothing*.

So if you don't need any set up then don't override `unittest.TestCase.setUp`.

However, if one of your `test_*` methods doesn't need the set up and the others do, I would recommend putting that in a separate class.

Comment: i believe @7hi4g0 has like 5 tests, and out of those 5 tests, he doesnt want the setup to run on one of them. INSTEAD of writing two seperate tests, one with setup one without

Comment: @TehTris:  In that case, it should be a separate test case and not mixed in with the others.

Comment: i agree 100%, but im sure there is at least one legit reason out there for this to be be able.

Comment: My problem is like @TehTris described. Probably it's better to have them in different classes. As I said, I'm fairly new to unit testing. Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: I just decided to not have a setup and embed each variant of the setup in the test. I'm not sure if that is the best way or not, but the setup was only 2 lines.

Comment: While rare, there are some legitimate use cases for skipping setup. I have 20 unittests for an application which authenticates with an external API. However, I have a single test which tests the authentication process itself.

Answer (score 16):

You can use Django's @tag decorator as a criteria to be used in the setUp method to skip if necessary.

```
# import tag decorator
from django.test.utils import tag

# The test which you want to skip setUp
@tag('skip_setup')
def test_mytest(self):
    assert True

def setUp(self):
    method = getattr(self,self._testMethodName)
    tags = getattr(method,'tags', {})
    if 'skip_setup' in tags:
        return #setUp skipped
    #do_stuff if not skipped
```

Besides skipping you can also use tags to do different setups.

P.S. If you are not using Django, the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/test/utils.py) for that decorator is really simple:

> ```
> def tag(*tags):
>     """
>     Decorator to add tags to a test class or method.
>     """
>     def decorator(obj):
>         setattr(obj, 'tags', set(tags))
>         return obj
>     return decorator
> ```

Comment: Wow, I really, really, like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

In `setUp()`, `self._testMethodName` contains the name of the test that will be executed. It's likely better to put the test into a different class or something, of course, but it's in there.

Answer (score 2):

It's feasible for user to skip some test methods based on its docstring, take an example as below:

```
import unittest

class simpleTest2(unittest.TestCase):
   def setUp(self):
      self.a = 10
      self.b = 20
      name = self.shortDescription()
      if name == "add":
         self.a = 10
         self.b = 20
         print name, self.a, self.b
      if name == "sub":
         self.a = 50
         self.b = 60
         print name, self.a, self.b
   def tearDown(self):
      print '\nend of test',self.shortDescription()

   def testadd(self):
      """add"""
      result = self.a+self.b
      self.assertTrue(result == 30)
   def testsub(self):
      """sub"""
      result = self.a-self.b
      self.assertTrue(result == -10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   unittest.main()
```

If the setup() method is used for most test methods except one exception, you can return directly if that method is met based on the comparison of docstring.