# Python unittest, do something only if test fails

Tags: python, unit-testing

When using the `unittest` library from python 3 I would like to do some actions only if a test fails (but this should be on a class level so I don't have to write it for each test). For example when using *behave* there was something like:

```
def after_step(context, step):
    if step.status == "failed":
        ...
```

Is there something similar for the `unittest`library and if not, what would be the easiest approach to do something similar?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Python's unittest results in a tearDown() method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414234/getting-pythons-unittest-results-in-a-teardown-method)

Comment: For anyone still having this problem, for the last 2 years I have been using the suggestion mentioned here and it's working fine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23176373/2535477

Answer (score 7):

I am trying to do something similarly recently and I found a way out:

```
import unittest

class MyTestResult(unittest.TestResult):
    def addFailure(self, test, err):
        # here you can do what you want to do when a test case fails 
        print('test failed!')
        super(MyTestResult, self).addFailure(test, err)

    def addError(self, test, err):
        # here you can do what you want to do when a test case raises an error
        super(MyTestResult, self).addError(test, err)

class MyUT(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_fail(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 2, '123')
        self.assertTrue("ABc".isupper())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(testRunner=unittest.TextTestRunner(resultclass=MyTestResult))
```

If you want to do different work according to different test case class, you can achieve it like this:

```
import unittest

class MyUT(unittest.TestCase):
    class TestResult(unittest.TestResult):
        def addFailure(self, test, err):
            print('do something when test case failed')
            super(MyUT.TestResult, self).addFailure(test, err)
        def addError(self, test, err):
            print('test case error')
            super(MyUT.TestResult, self).addError(test, err)

    def test_fail(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 2, "1=2")

class MyUT2(unittest.TestCase):
    class TestResult(unittest.TestResult):
        def addFailure(self, test, err):
            print('do something else when test case failed')
            super(MyUT2.TestResult, self).addFailure(test, err)
        def addError(self, test, err):
            print('test case error')
            super(MyUT2.TestResult, self).addError(test, err)

    def test_fail(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 2, "1=2")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    classes = [MyUT, MyUT2]
    for c in classes:
        suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(c)
        unittest.TextTestRunner(resultclass=c.TestResult).run(suite)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to do it with decorator:

```
class ExceptionHandler(object):
def __init__(self, f):
    self.f = f

def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        self.f(*args, **kwargs)
    except:
        print('do smth')
```

And in unit test:

```
@ExceptionHandler  
def test_fail(self):
    self.assert_false(True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to these cool things. Override the default exception handler by your custom which calls the original, and set your custom attributes:

```py
import sys
import unittest
has_failures = []

class IntegrationTests(unittest.TestCase):
    old_failureException = unittest.TestCase.failureException

    @property
    def failureException(self):
        has_failures.append('fail')
        return self.old_failureException

    def setUp(self):
        sys.stderr.write('Setup for %s\n' % self._testMethodName)

        if has_failures:
            self.skipTest("An test has failed, skipping everything else!")

    def test_thing1(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 2)

    def test_thing2(self):
        pass

def load_tests(loader, standard_tests, pattern):
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest( IntegrationTests( 'test_thing1' ) )
    suite.addTest( IntegrationTests( 'test_thing2' ) )
    return suite

# Comment this to run individual Unit Tests
load_tests = None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main(verbosity=3)
```

Results:

```
test_thing1 (__main__.IntegrationTests) ... Setup for test_thing1
FAIL
test_thing2 (__main__.IntegrationTests) ... Setup for test_thing2
skipped 'An test has failed, skipping everything else!'

======================================================================
FAIL: test_thing1 (__main__.IntegrationTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\User\Downloads\text.py", line 27, in test_thing1
    self.assertEqual(1, 2)
AssertionError: 1 != 2

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.003s

FAILED (failures=1, skipped=1)
```

References:

1. [Getting Python's unittest results in a tearDown() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414234/getting-pythons-unittest-results-in-a-teardown-method)
2. [if condition in setUp() ignore test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741133/if-condition-in-setup-ignore-test)
3. [How do you generate dynamic (parameterized) unit tests in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899/how-do-you-generate-dynamic-parameterized-unit-tests-in-python)
4. [How to get currently running testcase name from testsuite in unittest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797442/how-to-get-currently-running-testcase-name-from-testsuite-in-unittest)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution by overriding the run method of the TestCase class. This solution executes some code on the first error and stops the execution of the test.

```
class MyTestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    if not result.errors:
        super(MyTestClass, self).run(result)
    else:
        # Execute your code here, which should only run when an error 
        #  occurs.
        print("Failure")
```

This solution was inspired by the blog of [Kevin Sookocheff](https://sookocheff.com/post/python/halting-unittest-execution-at-first-error/).

Answer (score -1):

Using a private variable isn't very nice, but I haven't found other way to access the object which tracks the test results.

```
import unittest

class TmpTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def tearDown(self):
        result = self._resultForDoCleanups
        if not result.wasSuccessful():
            print "*** test failed"

    def testFoo(self):
        self.assertEqual(2, 2)

if "__main__" == __name__:
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Not sure what version of python you are using, but in python 3.6 _resultForDoCleanups is not member of TestCase.